# Problemas con dataTable filtros $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatable

Al correr el filtro aplicado con esta función

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push
```

la pantalla se pasma hasta que procesa todos los datos, ya que la tabla tine una cantidad grande de datos, hay alguna forma de evitar que eso pase o se redusca el tiempo en que procesa?

Comment: No cargues todos los datos y has que tu  tabla cargue datos según sea requerido por post proceso en el servidor para tus búsquedas, filtros o paginacion, hay cantidad de articulos  en internet de como hacerlo saludos

Comment: @stanchacon me podrias indicar alguno, o explicarme a que te refieres

Comment: aquí tienes un [ejemplo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F474RINIYYk) utilizando mysql y php. Basicamente a lo que me refiero es que cargues los datos de n en n cantidad y cuando quieras filtrar tus datos deja que la DB lo haga por ti y envié los resultados de vuelta.